# Python Gitlab API find creator of a project

Tags: python, gitlab, python-gitlab

```
import gitlab
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('http://gitlab.mycompany', private_token=access_token)
gl.auth()
projects = gl.projects.list()
pres = projects[0]
for project in projects:
    if 'myprojectname' in str(project):
        print(project)
        pres = project
# do something with pres
```

I'm trying to use Gitlab library in Python. When I print `str(project)`, it does not include info about who creates the repo. Also, when I run

```
for member in pres.members.list():
    print(member)
```

It only prints the invited member, it doesn't print the owner or the people who own the repo group.

Is it possible to find who creates a Gitlab repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ID of the project creator is exposed in the `creator_id` attribute in the projects endpoint (see upstream API docs at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects).

You can then use the Users API to get more details on the creator user (as described in https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/users.html):

```
import gitlab
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('http://gitlab.mycompany', private_token=access_token)
gl.auth()
projects = gl.projects.list(as_list=False)

for project in projects:
    creator = gl.users.get(project.creator_id)
    print(creator.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Search here for project members: https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/projects.html#project-members

There are more options you can try:
[image: PY-API built-in functions]

and last but not least if you can't find a way to solve your problems you can always do the trick with using pure gitlab API through requests module to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html

Comment: it shows the member, but doesn't show who actually created the repo.